# Sleeves of Many Garments. Multiple uses? Swarmsuit?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, magic

In my campaign, one of my players utilized [Sleeves of Many Garments](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/sleeves-of-many-garments). These go for 200gp, and can become any kind of mundane clothing, and say that the clothes revert afterwards. The player utilized these to suddenly don a non-magical swarmsuit that utterly baffled a swarm. I didn't have time when I first had to deal with it to consider how this would have worked out, but basically it nullified any of the swarms effects, and even the ability to do that once for 200gp seems a bit overpowered.. But the magic item seems to say that it reverts and can be used more than once.

That all said, here's what I'm wondering...

1. Should this item work multiple times? It doesn't explicitly stated that it does or does not in the item description. Cure Light potions cost 150gp (and only heal 1d8+1 hit points), at the lowest, and only work once. I've never seen a permanent item that works multiple times, yet the argument appears to be pro-multi-use.
2. Are the clothes an illusion in the first place? Are they real? The item indicates 'faint illusion,' not transmutation, nor some kind of enchantment. Does that means it's completely illusory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Sleeves](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/sleeves-of-many-garments) can be reused, just by removing them and re-donning them.

However, they can't duplicate the effects of the swarm suit, only it's appearance, as the transformation is illusory, only changing the clothes' appearance and feel with glamor:

> #### [Sleeves of Many Garments: Are the effects of sleeves of many garments illusion or transmutation?](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gg#v5748eaic9sl0)
>
> The effects are illusion (glamer) like the glamered weapon and armor properties. This means they can’t be disbelieved like a figment could, but they do not actually physically change the clothes. The transformation changes only the appearance, including the feel, smell, and other sensory aspects.
>
> (*Pathfinder* FAQ)

So they are reusable, but only for appearances, not to get real effects from real special clothing for free at will.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is a wondrous item that does not specify that it is one time. For reference, the [Feather Token](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/feather-token) does specify it is usable only one time. Another one time use item, this time for a slotted item, is the [Catching Cape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cape-catching), which specifically states

   > When the field is used, all magic is lost from the cloak, leaving only a mundane silvery garment.

   In response to Cure Light Potions, this is an item that heals hp, in comparison to an item that allows you to change your clothing... Seems to me that they are in very different categories.
2. The [Sleeves of Many Garments](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/sleeves-of-many-garments) specifically

   > transforms her current garments into any other non-magical set of clothing.

   They change your clothing to be something else. No illusion.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/containers-bags-boxes-more
Swarmsuit is from the APG.

Comment: The item's effect is illusory. It has an illusion aura and is based on [*disguise self*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/disguise-self), which is of the illusion (glamer) school.

Comment: @MrLemon Detecting as an illusion and being an illusion are not the same thing.  Having a spell as a prerequisite and being based off that spell aren't the same either.